# Cannot serialize big.Int from Go to C++

Tags: c++, go, cgo

I've got the following Golang function:

```golang
//export getBigInt
func getBigInt() unsafe.Pointer {
    return C.CBytes(big.NewInt(int64(7)).Bytes())
}
```

Which I'm trying to call from C:

```cpp
    uint8_t *byte_array = (uint8_t *)getBigInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(byte_array); ++i) {
        std::cout << (int)byte_array[i] << std::endl;
    }
```

However instead outputting 0..., 7 I'm getting:

```
7
0
0
0
0
0
0
32
```

Comment: `big.NewInt(int64(7)).Bytes()` is a slice with a single byte: `[7]` ([playground](https://play.golang.org/p/hEesypG6GIe)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sizeof(byte_array)` gives you the size of a pointer (in you case 8) and not the length of the array. The array is probably shorter than 8 elements causing your program to have undefined behavior.

Comment: Do you know if I could get the length of the array or I would need to return that from the function also?

Comment: If all you have is a pointer to the first element, then no, you can't get the array length from it. You need to return it too or maybe return a pointer/reference to an array of known size instead of just a pointer to the first element. I don't know how to do this from Go though.

Comment: Thanks. I've resorted to use a multi-argument return in Go. Going through `cgo`, the return value is wrapped as a struct return with arguments `r0` and `r1`. Works nicely :).